# RTMP to HLS conversion frame rate issues with ffmpeg/nginx

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, nginx, rtmp, hls

Currently, I'm pushing a RTMP stream to nginx 1.15.3 running on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from a raspberry pi 3 camera (which seems to be working well on its own, I can pull the stream with no issues on VLC and verify it's working) with the pi using this command:

```
raspivid -w 640 -h 480 -fps 5 -t 0 -b 1800000 -o - | ffmpeg -y -framerate 5 -f h264 -i - -c:v copy -map 0:0 -f flv -rtmp_buffer 100 -rtmp_live live rtmp://10.2.10.149/cam01/test
```

If I were to set the fps argument on raspivid to 25 and then get rid of the ffmpeg framerate argument, then this would be translating it just fine into a HLS stream with this command being run on the nginx server:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://10.2.10.149/cam01/test -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -acodec h264 -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://10.2.10.149/show1/stream1
```

However, I need it at the lower framerate and it seems trying to do that in any way really upsets ffmpeg because it will cause the stream to hitch a lot like it's waiting to load. I suspect it has something to do with ffmpeg having a default framerate of 25 or something, because in the RTMP stream, if I were to try setting only the fps argument in raspivid to 5 and not include the framerate argument in ffmpeg, then it would make the video hitch for a few seconds and then run at 5 times the speed of the video for a second since ffmpeg is still seemingly trying to run a 25 fps video.

Putting the framerate argument on the ffmpeg conversion command seems to make things even worse and I don't understand why this isn't working since it seems to work just fine for so many other people. I mainly used this guide to try and help me out in terms of setting up nginx and whatnot: https://docs.peer5.com/guides/setting-up-hls-live-streaming-server-using-nginx/#4-pushing-live-stream-to-nginx-using-rtmp

I'm also going to put my nginx.conf in here for everyone to see, and note that I'm having this issue whenever I try to pull the video up via a webpage or with VLC directly getting the network stream:

```
worker_processes  auto;
events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
    chunk_size 4096;

    application show1 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls1/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
application show2 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls2/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
application show3 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls3/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
application show4 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls4/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
application show5 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls5/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
application show6 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls6/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
application show7 {
        live on;
        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls7/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
    }
    application cam01 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
application cam02 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
application cam03 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
application cam04 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
application cam05 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
application cam06 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
application cam07 {
        live on;
        record off;
    }
}
}

http {
sendfile off;
tcp_nopush on;
default_type application/octet-stream;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        # Disable cache
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

        # CORS setup
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

        # allow CORS preflight requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        types {
            application/dash+xml mpd;
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }

        root /mnt/;
        location /index.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
        location /testing.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
        location /test.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam01.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam02.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam03.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam04.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam05.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam06.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    location /cam07.html {
            default_type "text/html";
        }
    }
}
}
```

If I need to include any more details, feel free to let me know, I just need to get this working properly instead of all of the issues I just explained, any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Edit 1: I'm also noticing that on top of the hitches and cut outs from the stream using the second command as described earlier, it seems to get "stuck" on a certain frame sometimes, not sure if this is more helpful or not, just wanted to make sure I have all the information I can on here.

Edit 2: I'm beginning to believe this is more of an issue with nginx because when I point the first command to the /show1/stream1 location which converts the rtmp to hls without running the second command which I thought was completely necessary, I'm getting the same exact issue in the same way. I don't know much about nginx and nothing I'm finding online is helping much either. Would highly appreciate insight, I do know that hls will always have a big delay and that's not what I'm asking to fix, I'm asking to fix the cut outs and the hitching.

Edit 3: I may have actually somewhat cracked this, I noticed on the raspivid command, setting the bitrate higher did seem to alleviate this, however, even if I set the bit rate to an absurd or even not so absurd, but still overkill amount, it still occasionally cuts out a few frames randomly every couple minutes and I'm not entirely sure why. Would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to everyone I confused, it turns out this code is all correct (actually, I don't even need the second command, I can just feed it directly to the hls in nginx no problem from the pi). What's going on is ffmpeg REALLY doesn't like taking in anything less than 7 FPS when doing this kind of streaming which is still adequate for my purposes. This should honestly be documented somewhere (well, I guess it is now, but still).

Edit: The camera I'm using may also be affecting it since I just realized that some of my cameras have a minimum frame rate of 7.